# .NET Library using 32bit OCX fails on 64 bit win7

Tags: c#, winforms, com, 64-bit

I have used a 32bit OCX in my .NET 4 project built on a 32 bit platform with x86 target.  When I go to run this on a 64bit windows 7 platform the DLL that has the 32 bit OCX generates the bad image exception fault.  The remaining .NET libraries seem to run fine.

Does anyone have an sugguestions on what I need to do to make this work.  Are there any examples on-line for this issue?

Comment: It sounds like your application is being treated like a x64 process so when you attempt to access a 32-bit OCX logically it will have a problem with that.  You need a 64-bit version of the OCX if thats the case.

Comment: +1^. Th x86 target does not seem to stick and the process is loaded into 64 bit space.

Comment: Simple fix: set the platform target on your *exe project* to x86.  Project + Properties, Build tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project properties set the platform target to x86:
[image]

Comment: Specifically, this needs to be done for the EXE project, not for the DLL.

Comment: Actually, yes this does work.  I changed the compulation settings but missed the project setting on the main exe for the project!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`CorFlags.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to force  your Assembly to run in 32 bit mode:

```
corflags.exe  "c:\your executable.exe" /32BIT+ /Force
```

Answer (score 0):

64-bit process can load only 64-bit libraries. There is no exception from this rule. Standard Microsoft recommendation in this case is to use some kind of interprocess communication. Specifically, COM exe server can work in such situation.

So, you need to run your application in 32 bits, or have in-process COM server in 64 bits, or use interprocess communication.